# How to get access token from Azure AD using Windows Integrated login from ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, credentials

Is there any way to get access token from Azure AD using Windows Integrated login from ASP.NET MVC? I've just tried to use ADAL to login providing tenant, client credentials (id and secret) and user login but it responds that "Managed users must provide password".

That's an organizational account and I don't want to show consent screen to the user if they even need to provide password.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using OpenID Connect. I believe you can use the OpenID Connect sign-in request by decorating a class or method with the [Authorize] attribute. See this document for more details to see if it helps. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless/